# How to combine bar plots on same wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyr, ggpubr

I need to show Memory and CPU usage for every Numa node on same wraps, so architecture was visible. Something like this:

[image: result example]

This is code I have:

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

numa.nodes <- tibble (
  numa_name = c("numa_01","numa_01","numa_01","numa_01","numa_01","numa_01","numa_02","numa_02","numa_02","numa_02"),
  counter_name =c("cpu01","cpu02","cpu03","cpu04","memory_used","memory_total","cpu01","cpu02","memory_used","memory_total"),
    value = c(sample(0:100,4), sample(0:32,1), 32, sample(0:100,1), sample(0:100,1), sample(0:128,1), 128)
)

numa.nodes <- numa.nodes %>% add_row(
  numa_name = c("numa_03","numa_03","numa_03","numa_03","numa_03","numa_03","numa_04","numa_04","numa_04","numa_04"),
  counter_name =c("cpu01","cpu02","cpu03","cpu04","memory_used","memory_total","cpu01","cpu02","memory_used","memory_total"),
  value = c(sample(0:100,4), sample(0:32,1), 32, sample(0:100,1), sample(0:100,1), sample(0:128,1), 128)
  )


numa.nodes <- numa.nodes %>% mutate(counter_name=factor(counter_name,levels = unique(counter_name),ordered = T))

print(numa.nodes)


cpu_p <- numa.nodes %>% filter(counter_name != c("memory_used", "memory_total")) %>% 
ggplot() +
  aes(x = counter_name, y = value, label = value) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', fill = "#00AFBB",  color='black') +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity',aes(y=100),alpha=0.2,fill='white',color='black') +
  facet_wrap(vars(numa_name), strip.position = 'bottom', scales = "free_x")+
  geom_text(size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(strip.placement = 'outside',
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        legend.position = 'none',
        axis.text = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        axis.title = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        legend.text = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        legend.title = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        strip.text = element_text(color='black',face='bold')) +
        labs(x='CPU',y="Usage %") 



mem_p <- numa.nodes %>% filter(counter_name == c("memory_used", "memory_total")) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = counter_name,values_from=value) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=numa_name,y=memory_total)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity',aes(fill='memory_total'),color='black')+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity',aes(y=memory_used,fill='memory_used'),color='black') +
  facet_wrap(vars(numa_name), strip.position = 'bottom', scales = "free_x")+
  theme_bw()+
  geom_text(aes(y=memory_total,
                label=memory_total),size = 3) +
  geom_text(aes(y=memory_used,label=memory_used),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),
            size=3)+
  theme(strip.placement = 'outside',
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        legend.position = 'top',
        axis.text = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        axis.title = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        legend.text = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        legend.title = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        strip.text = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank()) +
  labs(x='Memory',y="Usage %")+
  labs(fill='Counter')

library("ggpubr")

ggarrange (cpu_p, mem_p)
```

[image: my result]

Unfortunately my code has two problems.

1. My result draw - is not CPU and Memory together for each node. I need to combine Memory+CPU somehow.
2. It's weird that I work with tall and wide data on graphs that look very similar.

The problems are:

- the number of CPU's could be 1-8, if I use pivoting for CPU's, I will have N/A for some numa nodes,
- scale for CPU is 100%, I use y=100 to show scale, scale for memory is total memory (used memory layered on total memory),
- I can't use staking and can't put counters just left to right - memory and cpu data seems to be processed different way.

Is it possible to show CPU and Memory of each Numa node near each other? Also any way to use Tall or Wide data, not both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've taken a programmatic approach using the ggpubr package for arranging plots:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)

plot_numa = function(num){

  df = numa.nodes %>% filter(str_detect(numa_name, num))
  
  cpu_plot = df %>%
    filter(str_detect(counter_name, "cpu")) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = counter_name)) +
    geom_col(aes(y = 100), fill = "white", color = "black") +
    geom_col(aes(y = value), fill = "black", color = "black") +
    geom_text(aes(y = value, label = paste0(value,"%")), nudge_y = 5, color = "black") +
    theme_bw() +
    labs(x = "CPU", y = "")
  
  memory_plot = df %>%
    filter(str_detect(counter_name, "memory")) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = counter_name, values_from = value) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = "")) +
    geom_col(aes(y = memory_total), fill = "white", color = "black") +
    geom_col(aes(y = memory_used), fill = "black", color = "black") +
    geom_text(aes(label = paste(memory_total, "GB"), y = memory_total), nudge_y = -2, color = "black") +
    geom_text(aes(label = paste(memory_used, "GB"), y = memory_used), nudge_y = -2, color = "white") +
    theme_bw() +
    labs(x = "Memory", y = "")
  
  ggpubr::ggarrange(cpu_plot, memory_plot, ncol = 2) %>% ggpubr::annotate_figure(top = paste("NUMA",num))
  
}

ggpubr::ggarrange(plotlist = map(.x = c("01","02","03","04"), .f = ~plot_numa(num = .x)))
```

This outputs:

[image]

You can refine as you like, but this gets you a lot of the way there.